# With redux, how do you avoid recalculating component state for complex pages?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Suppose a complex component is subscribed to the redux store. The first time the component is mounted, we aggregate a lot of data from the store and create a "ModelView" object.

Then, imagine that this component receive an event to update itself because there's a new state. It seems like the render method would need to re-aggregate all the data from the store to know if there's a difference. I.e. we cannot do a simple comparison because the ModelView object is different than what's in the store.

You may ask "Why a ModelView", why not just read data from the store in render(). This is a fine approach for simple pages, but for complex pages the lag is noticeable and it is just not possible.

Also, a view may have an internal state that is different from the store. For instance, maybe a few tasks have been updated in the store, but we don't want to change the UI because that would be confusing for the user.. we'd rather show a "Click to see new change" button for instance. One approach to that is to store *everything* in the store.. both the ModelView AND the normal state.. but isn't that overkill? Or said differently, shouldn't the ModelView be stored inside the component itself?

Comment: Have you looked at reselect? That was built to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) is a recipe describing how a memoized “view model” can be derived in a composable way from the Redux store thanks with [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).